# Bulk deleting documents from aggregate

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I am trying to use a bulk delete on the results of a mongoose aggregate query.

```
var bulk = Collection.collection.initializeUnorderedBulkOp();
var cursor = Collection.aggregate(query).cursor({batchSize: 1000}).exec();

cursor.each(function(error, doc){
  if(doc){
    console.log(doc);
    bulk.find({_id : doc._id}).removeOne();
  }
});

if(bulk.length > 0) {
  bulk.execute(function(error){
    if(error){
      console.error(error);
      callback(error);
    }else{
      console.log(bulk.length + " documents deleted");
      callback(null);
    }
  });
} else {
  console.log("no documents to delete");
  callback(null);
}
```

This results in the "no documents to delete" being printed before the results of the aggregate in the each loop. Normally I would expect there to be a callback function for a database operation. I have tried adding a callback function to the params of exec, but the function never gets hit:

```
var cursor = Collection.aggregate(query).cursor({batchSize: 1000}).exec(function(error, result){
  console.log(error);
  console.log(result);
  callback();
});
```

Comment: Bulk operations on-line? Wow! I think that you must don't that. I suggest you to use a nightly batch process on the server that has to put on your scheduler.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Listen to the data and end events on the cursor:

```
cursor.on( 'data', function( data ) {
    bulk.find( { "_id" : data._id } ).removeOne();
});

cursor.on( 'end', function() {
    if ( bulk.length === 0 ) {
        callback();
    } else {
        bulk.execute(function (error) {
            if (error) {
                callback(error);
            } else {
                callback();
            }
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: I'd also execute the bulk afte a period of time since it can crash the application because it runs out of memory. Let's say after every 5000k commands.

Answer (score 0):

What version of Mongoose? There's an [issue on github](https://github.com/Automattic/mongoose/issues/2306) that might be relevant. So maybe try:

```
var stream = Model
.aggregate(pipeline)
.cursor({ batchSize: 1000 })
.exec().stream();

stream.on('data', function(doc) {
  // ...
});
```